# Did Ramakrishna ever meet Dayanand Saraswati?

Tags: history, ramakrishna, dayananda-saraswati

I read somewhere(maybe Ramakrishna Kathamrta) that Ramakrishna had a meeting with Dayanand Saraswati(founder of Arya Samaj). Is it true? If so what topics were discussed between then and what conclusions were drawn?

Answer (score 6):

In Sw. [Saradanandaji's biography of Thakurji](https://www.indiadivine.org/content/topic/1664574-ramakrishna-and-dayananda/), [Vol. II,p.635; 5th revised ed. 1979]:

> Once Swami Dayananda Sarasvati, the founder of the Arya Samaj, came to
>   Bengal on a tour and lived for some time in a gentleman's garden in
>   the village called Sinthi in Baranagar, situated in the north of
>   Calcutta. Although he was very well-known for his scholarship, he had
>   not then begun to preach his own doctrine, nor had he founded his 
>   organisation.
>
> On hearing of him, one day the Master went there to pay him a visit.
>   In the course of a conversation on Dayananda, the Master said to us on
>   one occasion,
>
> " I went to see him in the garden of Sinthi.; I found that he had
>   acquired a little power; his chest was always red. He was in the state
>   of Vaikhari, speaking on scriptural  subjects night and day; by the
>   application of grammar, he was twisting the meaning of many words. He
>   had in his mind the egoism , 'I will do something, I will preach a
>   doctrine.' "

---

Sri Dayananda Saraswati's [observation](https://www.kathamrita.org/kathamrita/volume-1-section-13) on Sri Ramakrishna Paramahamsa:

> Mahimacharan and other devotees are sitting and drinking the nectar of
>   Sri Ramakrishna’s words, which are like variously-coloured jewels. The
>   devotees pick up as many as they can, but their laps are already full,
>   so heavy that they cannot be lifted. Their capacity is limited; they
>   can contain no more.
>
> Sri Ramakrishna is solving all the problems that have arisen in the
>   human heart since the creation of the world. Padmalochan, Narayan
>   Shastri, Gauri Pundit, Dayananda Saraswati, and other scholars of the
>   scriptures sit in silent awe.
>
> When Dayananda saw Sri Ramakrishna in the state of samadhi, he
>   lamented, “***We have studied so much of the Vedas and the Vedanta, but
>   in this great man we see its manifestation.*** He proves that the learned
>   only drink buttermilk when they churn the scriptures. Only such great
>   men as he eat the butter.”