# What were the views of different saints on ramakrishna paramhamsa and vivekananda

Tags: vivekananda, ramakrishna

Did any traditional saint considered ramakrishna paramhamsa and swami vivekananda as self realized beings?

Comment: Traditional saint means?

Comment: @Rickross for e.g saint belonging from shankara tradition or sri vaishnav sampradya who is well versed in scriptures under guru

Comment: Is keshavchandra an example for you?

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi nope

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37769/23924 in this swami dayanand saraswati says shri ramakrishna as self realized